# curl doesn't send (the last line) cookie from file

Tags: curl, cookies

Platform: Windows7

Test with `http://httpbin.org`

1. Set a cookie in the browser `http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/name/value`
2. I use the *EditThisCookie* Chrome extension to output the cookie into Netscape HTTP Cookie format (select Netscape HTTP cookie file in the *EditThisCookie* settings ).

filename: cookie

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by EditThisCookie
httpbin.org FALSE   /   FALSE   0   name    value
```

3. In Powershell, I run

```
curl "http://httpbin.org/cookies" -H "Proxy-Connection: keep-alive" -H "Pragma: no-cache" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7" --compressed --insecure -b cookie --verbose -o bb.html
```

The cookie is not sent according the verbose information (No HTTP cookie header is shown in request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Only  the last line cookie won't be sent if you don't add an extra blank line.**

Solution:

Add an extra blank line in the file.

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by EditThisCookie
httpbin.org FALSE   /   FALSE   0   name    value
```

Then it works.

https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/4946

Comment: Clarification: each cookie line in that file needs to end with a newline for curl to accept it. There's no need for "an extra blank line".